# Infopath doesn't render background colors/pictures w/ Outlook Task/Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, workflow, infopath, task

I am using Infopath forms to collect information to trigger my Windows Workflow sitting on Sharepoint 2007. The Infopath forms have logo's and branding which only show up on the Sharepoint portal but the infopath forms which are emailed when tasks are created during the workflow look different as in the background colors (Infopath Theme) and jpeg's are not there...web form compatibility was for checked in all appropriate places....any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue here...InfoPath seems to cache the form on the client(seems to check for the form’s unique URN in the cache) which means that if you attempt to click on the email “Edit this task…” the new form is not downloaded, instead the InfoPath form from the cache is displayed.

I am looking at a few ways into fix this. In the meanwhile, to be able see the jpeg's and background colors on the InfoPath form, Run the following on your cmd window (Sorry it’s “hacky” for now)

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\INFOPATH.EXE" /cache clearall

Will write a blog post when I figure out a nice way  to fix this

Jacob